# How to replace ascii characters present in between a String using java

Tags: java, ascii

I have a string `Hi , Thank you for opening an account with XYZ. We&#39;re excited to have you on board.`

I need to get rid of `&#39;` from the string and get equivalent character in place of it which is apostrophe (').

I need general code to replace the ascii characters.

Comment: These aren't "ascii characters", they are HTML entities.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.replace()`:

```
String str = "Hi , Thank you for opening an account with XYZ. We&#39;re excited to have you on board.";
str.replace("&#39;","\'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is example

```
public class Guru99Ex1 {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String S1 = new String("the quick fox jumped");
    System.out.println("Original String is ': " + S1);
    System.out.println("String after replacing 'fox' with 'dog': " + S1.replace("fox", "dog"));
    System.out.println("String after replacing all 't' with 'a': " + S1.replace('t', 'a'));

}
```

}